# SQL syntax error in php code

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing value from android using `POST` and run the query in **SQL DB** using **PHP**. I am always getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1.

The code is working fine if i pass the values directly insted `$_POST[]`.

I've gone through SO but no questions solved my problem. I tried with `mysql_real_escape_string($searchTermBits)` also but that doesn't worked.

**PHP**:

```
<?php
$username    = "xxxx";
$password    = "xxxx";
$host        = "xxxx";
$database    = "xxxx";
$server      = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection  = mysql_select_db($database, $server);
$search      = $_POST["deskey"];
$search      = explode(" ", $search);
$commonwords = "a,an,and,I,it,is,do,does,for,from,go,how,the,etc,in,on,are";
$commonwords = explode(",", $commonwords);
foreach ($search as $value)
  {
    if (!in_array($value, $commonwords))
      {
        $query[] = $value;
      }
  }

$query          = implode(" ", $query);
$searchTerms    = explode(" ", $query);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
  {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term))
      {
        $searchTermBits[] = "description LIKE '%$term%'";
      }
  }

$myquery = "SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE " . implode(' OR ', mysql_real_escape_string($searchTermBits)) . "";
$query   = mysql_query($myquery);
if (!$query)
  {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
  }
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++)
  {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  }
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($server);
?>
```

What changes can i make this code to work with `$_POST[]`.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $myquery` ????

Comment: Try this : `'description LIKE "%'.$term.'%" ' `

Comment: @Diksha that piece of code is perfectly fine, that's not the issue.

Comment: @RavinderReddy SELECT * FROM logins WHERE description LIKE  '%xxx%' AND description LIKE  '%xxxx%'    if $search = "xxx xxxx".

Comment: Query you posted looks good but differs from what is used in your code. Can you post the exact output of `echo $myquery` statement. This statement must just be the very next statement after defining `myquery` variable.

Comment: No changes same code only.

Comment: @user2269164 you are imploding with `OR` and the result query has `AND` really weird isn't it? :D

Comment: Your imploded strings do not act as strings that's why it's returning a syntax error. `col IN ('" . implode("','", arrayOfStrings) . "')"`

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: @Sal00m - Agree, but that doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Try moving that `mysql_real_escape_string()` up, for example `$term = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($term));`. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is supposed to neutralize SQL code in variables, and you are running SQL code through it intentionally.

Comment: @Jhn - Can you provide more details? i am not able to understand it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Tried but same problem. Thanks.

Comment: When you implode the string and concatenate it in a `sql` query string. Say `'IN (' . implode(',', ['hey', 'ya']) . ')'` --- This will result to `IN (hey, ya)`. What you need to make sure is this output: `IN ('hey', 'ya')`. It's just  a wild guess. tho